# How to solve issue with getting Data using URL Session?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios10

I am using URL Session to get Data from a web API and load them in a tableView.
Every thing is working fine except that whenever I get the data the first time, the data is always returned the same even if it was changed in the backend side.
The data is only returned new when I delete the application and install it again.
Any idea on how to solve this please?

Comment: can you show some code? sounds like a caching issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying that when deleting the application your problem is solved then the issue is in caching.

To solve this either add:

```
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

or:

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
 config.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
 let session: URLSession = URLSession(configuration: config)
```

This will solve your problem and ignore caching so that the data will be returned new everytime.

Comment: Thanks it worked it seems it was a caching issue and removeAllCachedResponses solved it.

Comment: You can also specify on the server that the client should not cache the response, if you can modify the server response.  https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9